# How to highlight cells based on other cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got an order spreadsheet, and I want to highlight cells (kind of like a danger text) if two cells meet criteria. The cells are not adjacent, and I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

Here's an example of my sheet:

```
   A            B            C              D              E
OrderID    OrderDate    ItemNumber    OrderLocation    Quantity
 1234      MM/DD/YYYY       2           City, State       7
 5879          ....         6            ...              43
```

So for example, I want to highlight the OrderID if the ItemNumber is 4 the quantity is greater than or equal to 15. Is there a formula to do this?

Comment: You'll need conditional formatting on the OrderID cells for this, and use a formula that says something like `=AND(C2=4;E2>=15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the cells you want to format. You can select one column, several columns or the entire table if you want to apply your conditional format to rows.
- Click Conditional formatting > New Rule…

[image: See screenshot]